# Web Client breaking changes in .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I've an application that uses web client to download data and the program works without any problems under .NET 4.0 but throws the following exception under .NET 4.5:

The type initializer for 'System.uriParser' threw an exception

Several breaking changes involving System.URI are listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx

But, I do not know which one applies to the scenario of downloading a file from the web using webclient. My question is what is the likely cause of this exception and appropriate resolution?

Comment: Could you provide more details about the exception?

Comment: What is the URL that causes the exception?

Comment: @Curtis White I'm from .NET Framework compatibility team. I'd like to understand this better. Could you send sample project to netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? Sincerely, Varun Gupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange problem. The solution was to change the target framework form .NET 4.0 Client Profile to .NET 4.0. This is a breaking change that only occurs when .NET 4.5 is installed.

This "in-place" upgrade stuff is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `System.Uri` changes in **Core** section in the breaking changes document you've linked in your question. Exception details (ie. message) will help you narrow down the affected area.